# Ansible kubernetes.core.k8s Module -kubeconfig

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am executing my ansible playbook like this:

ansible-playbook -i <ip-address>, oke.yml -vvv

and the content of the playbook is as follows:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: opc
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  tasks:
  # - name: Install Python packages for the module "kubernetes.core.k8s"
  #   ansible.builtin.pip:
  #     name: " {{ item }}"
  #   loop:
  #     - kubernetes
  #     - PyYAML
  #     - jsonpatch

  - name: Create k8s Namespace
    # environment:
    #   K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG: /home/opc/.kube/config
    #   K8S_AUTH_CONTEXT: context-cyxq7k7hsia
    kubernetes.core.k8s:
      api_version: v1
      kind: Namespace
      name: test
```

Apparently, ansible is looking for the kubeconfig on the ansible controller host and not on the remote host where it is configured. Any help is highly appreciated.

Below is the output that that i get. My kubeconfig exists on the remote host where i am connecting and is available in the default location of ~/.kube.config

```
TASK [Create k8s Namespace] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /Users/fnafey/Documents/Scripts/Terraform/TerraformWorkshop/OKE/Ansible/oke_monitoring.yml:16
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: fnafey
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~fnafey && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /Users/fnafey/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /Users/fnafey/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671313489.196291-9247-116092304879285 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1671313489.196291-9247-116092304879285="` echo /Users/fnafey/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671313489.196291-9247-116092304879285 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /Users/fnafey/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/modules/k8s.py
<127.0.0.1> PUT /Users/fnafey/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-9236vjnfx02a/tmprc8yyp58 TO /Users/fnafey/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671313489.196291-9247-116092304879285/AnsiballZ_k8s.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /Users/fnafey/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671313489.196291-9247-116092304879285/ /Users/fnafey/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671313489.196291-9247-116092304879285/AnsiballZ_k8s.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/6.6.0/libexec/bin/python3.10 /Users/fnafey/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671313489.196291-9247-116092304879285/AnsiballZ_k8s.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /Users/fnafey/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671313489.196291-9247-116092304879285/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
  File "/var/folders/4y/wn254gb10ks_xlb5y4tvn3kw0000gn/T/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload_8nq86hcx/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload.zip/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/module_utils/common.py", line 266, in get_api_client
    _load_config()
  File "/var/folders/4y/wn254gb10ks_xlb5y4tvn3kw0000gn/T/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload_8nq86hcx/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload.zip/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/module_utils/common.py", line 233, in _load_config
    kubernetes.config.load_kube_config(config_file=None, **optional_arg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/6.6.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 813, in load_kube_config
    loader = _get_kube_config_loader(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/6.6.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 770, in _get_kube_config_loader
    raise ConfigException(
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_key": null,
            "api_version": "v1",
            "append_hash": false,
            "apply": false,
            "ca_cert": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "context": null,
            "continue_on_error": false,
            "delete_options": null,
            "force": false,
            "generate_name": null,
            "host": null,
            "impersonate_groups": null,
            "impersonate_user": null,
            "kind": "Namespace",
            "kubeconfig": null,
            "label_selectors": null,
            "merge_type": null,
            "name": "test",
            "namespace": null,
            "no_proxy": null,
            "password": null,
            "persist_config": null,
            "proxy": null,
            "proxy_headers": null,
            "resource_definition": null,
            "server_side_apply": null,
            "src": null,
            "state": "present",
            "template": null,
            "username": null,
            "validate": null,
            "validate_certs": null,
            "wait": false,
            "wait_condition": null,
            "wait_sleep": 5,
            "wait_timeout": 120
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to load kubeconfig due to Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found."
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: "Apparently, ansible is looking for the kubeconfig on the ansible controller host and not on the remote host where it is configured." You're not running the task on a remote host: your play is targeting `localhost`, so of course the module is looking for a kubeconfig file on your local system.

Comment: What's the correct value for hosts should be? I have tried the value " all" and it gets stuck there

Comment: I can't tell you that. On which host do you *want* to run things?

Comment: I tried adding the IP address to the hosts variable, with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Downloading and using `kubeconfig` from the controller host is the preferred way to running `kubectl` commands against remote kubernetes cluster.

That's why, I suggest to download `kubeconfig` for Kubernetes cluster you are authenticating against, put it on ansible controller host and configure ansible to use it using `K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG` environment variable.

Below playbook runs against `localhost` and uses `kubeconfig` to run against remote kubernetes cluster for creating of namespace assuming the current context is using the `kubeconfig`.

```
- name: prepare for jenkins installation
  hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no
  environment:
    K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG: "path_to_kubeconfig_on_localhost"
  tasks:
    - name: Create ns
      kubernetes.core.k8s:
        name: "jenkins"
        api_version: v1
        kind: Namespace
        state: present
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I do realize that the preferred way to run k8s module is to trigger it from the Controller host. However, the team project requires the use of a centralized host for managing Kubernetes resources hence the requirement is not to use the controller host, and use the jump host for configuration.
This is where I am stuck and need help around.

Comment: You can run the playbooks on the jumphost. So jumpost will be ansible controller host. In that case, you'll need to download the kubeconfig to it.

Comment: this will be equivalent to running `kubectl` commands on the jumphost for interacting with the cluster... Ansible will do it for you using python kubernetes library.